# How would I be able to grab the value from a drop down list control after the control has been bound with a filled data set?

Tags: c#, webforms

How would I be able to grab the value from a dropdown list control after the control has been bound with a filled data set? Specifically, this control lives in my footer template and when the user tries to add a new row the selected item needs to be retrieved. The problem is after the dropdown list has been populated when you click on "add new" the value always returns null.

**ROW COMMAND FUNCTION:**

```
protected void userView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList addUserRole = (DropDownList)userView.FooterRow.FindControl("editUserRole");
  string sqlCommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(USERNAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ROLEIDFK, DEPTIDFK, ACTIVE) VALUES(@username, @phone, @email, @roleidfk, @deptidfk, @active)";
  scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roleidfk", addUserRole.SelectedValue.ToString()); // >>>> Returns "AddUserRole was null"
}
```

**DROPDOWN DATABINDING:**

```
    private DataTable GetData (string query)
    {
        var connection = sqlConnect.connect();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open(); 
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt); 
            }
        }
        return dt;

    protected void userView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

        }

        if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {

            DropDownList ddlUser = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlRoles") as DropDownList );
            //query.addDataSetDdl(roles, "DESCRIPTION", "ROLEID", ddlUser);

            ddlUser.DataSource = GetData("SELECT * FROM Roles"); 

            ddlUser.DataTextField = "DESCRIPTION";
            ddlUser.DataValueField = "ROLEID";
            ddlUser.DataBind(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `FindControl` call does not use the correct id of the dropdpwnlist - at least it differs from the one that you use when databinding the dropdownlist:

```
DropDownList addUserRole = (DropDownList)userView.FooterRow.FindControl("editUserRole")
```

vs

```
DropDownList ddlUser = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlRoles") as DropDownList );
```

`FindControl` returns `null` if the control cannot be found, so if you use the correct id, the problem should be solved.